# `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel

Tags: rust

I am trying to use the `clap` crate to do some argument parsing. However, when I add it to my `Cargo.toml`, I get the following error when I do `cargo build`:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling rustix v0.36.5
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
  --> /home/wheeler/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustix-0.36.5/src/lib.rs:99:26
   |
99 | #![cfg_attr(rustc_attrs, feature(rustc_attrs))]
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> /home/wheeler/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustix-0.36.5/src/lib.rs:116:5
    |
116 |     feature(core_intrinsics)
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> /home/wheeler/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustix-0.36.5/src/lib.rs:116:13
    |
116 |     feature(core_intrinsics)
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `rustix` due to 3 previous errors
```

There isn't anything in the documentation for `clap` that says that it requires the use of the nighly builds. I didn't understand why this was happening, so I created a VM to try to replicate the issue (using Vagrant). Here is the Vagrantfile:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/fedora37"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<~'EOF'
    set -e
    set -x
    sudo dnf update -y
    curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
    source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
    mkdir -p test-project
    cd test-project
    cat << 'EOFF' | sed -r 's/^ {2}//' > Cargo.toml
      [package]
      name = "rpg"
      version = "0.1.0"
      edition = "2021"
      
      [dependencies]
      clap = { version = "4.0.29", features = ["derive"] }
    EOFF
    cat Cargo.toml
    mkdir -p src
    cd src
    touch main.rs
    cat << 'EOFF' | sed -r 's/^ {2}//' > main.rs
      use clap::Parser;
      
      /// Simple program to greet a person
      #[derive(Parser, Debug)]
      #[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
      struct Args {
         /// Name of the person to greet
         #[arg(short, long)]
         name: String,
      
         /// Number of times to greet
         #[arg(short, long, default_value_t = 1)]
         count: u8,
      }
      
      fn main() {
         let args = Args::parse();
      
         for _ in 0..args.count {
             println!("Hello {}!", args.name)
         }
      }
    EOFF
    cat main.rs
    cd ..
    cargo build

  EOF
end
```

But when I do `vagrant up`, the VM updates, installs rust, and compiles my little sample program just fine (it is the exact same `main.rs` and `Cargo.toml` I have on the host system).

Why does `clap` need the nightly version on my host machine, but not in my test VM?

Comment: Errors like this often come from an outdated rust toolchain. What version of rust are you running in both cases?

Comment: @cafce25 Indeed. I stumbled over this myself not long ago. A `rustup update` fixed it for me.

Comment: `stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)` is the version reported when I do `rustup update`.

Comment: Does any of [your cargo config files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) contain a `[build]` section with `rustflags = "--cfg rustc_attrs --cfg core_intrinsics"`

Comment: I tried every location, and didn't find any cargo config files to begin with lol

Answer (score 14):

There was something cached in the `target` directory that was causing this. I deleted the `target` directory and re-ran `cargo build` and the issue went away.

Comment: Instead of manually deleting the directory, you can also run cargo clean.

Answer (score -4):

To use `feature` attribute, you need the `nightly` release channel. To switch to nightly, execute `rustup default nightly` command.

Comment: That's obvious but the feature is in rustix a dependency and shouldn't be enabled in the first place.

Comment: @cafce25, anyway rustc just always does this. You cannot use a library that contains `feature` attribute on `stable` channel. There are only two ways - to switch to nigtly or not to use the library at all.

Comment: Then why would it compile with the same compiler in a vagrant container on 1.65.0 and on my machine... you're missing the point.

Comment: downvoted as it doesn't answer the question.